# Adding an Element not working (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm blocked on this since 3 days :
Here is my view :

```
<h1>Liste des livres</h1>

<% @books.each do |book| %>

  <p><a href="/books/<%= book.id %>"><%= book.title %></a></p>

<% end %>

<%-# Adding a book %>

<%= form_tag "/books", method: "post" do %>
  <input type="text" name="title" />
  <input type="submit" value="Ajouter le livre" />
<% end %>
```

And here is the controller :

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @books = Book.all
  end

  def create
    Book.create title: params[:title]
    redirect_to "/books"
  end

  def show
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    Book.find(params[:id]).update title: params[:title]
    redirect_to "/books/#{params[:id]}"
  end

  def destroy
    Book.find(params[:id]).destroy
    redirect_to "/books"
  end

end
```

Finally my routes :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'pages/home'
  get 'books/index'
  get 'books' => 'books#index'
  post 'books' => 'books#index'
  get 'books/:id' => 'books#show'
  patch 'books/:id' => 'books#update'
  delete 'books/:id' => 'books#destroy'
```

Now when i insert a book name and click on the button i see this in the terminal :

```
Started POST "/books" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-17 15:38:39 +0100
Processing by BooksController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"TgLJMVchOq/3yKT2cii82ywS6qNVH8xI9E4mMnuNeI/BK/5SXnRosM0+mKwDlxOEO3WtEg5zttU7Tx69YYJkKQ==", "title"=>"ahah"}
  Book Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "books".* FROM "books"
  Rendered books/index.html.erb within layouts/application (1.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 27ms (Views: 26.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

But when the pages has refreshed nothing is added and if i open another terminal window and i check in a rails console with Book.all there is nothing more then the original list of books.
Is there something wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your routes your `post` request should point to the `create` action.

So it should look like this: `post 'books' => 'books#create'` not `post 'books' => 'books#index'`

Comment: Thanks, i didn't noticed that problem, you really saved my day

Comment: He'd be better off replacing all of those routes with `resources :books, only: [:index, :create, :show, :update, :destroy]` imo.